# Mime type validation fails for high resolution images in Symfony1.0

Tags: php, symfony1

Symfony1 mime type validation results in wrong error message as it fails to validate the high resolution images. My validation codes in the validate.yml is as follows:

```
mime_types:       
      - 'image/jpg'
      - 'image/jpeg'
      - 'image/png'
      - 'image/gif'
      - 'image/bmp' 
      - 'application/pdf'       
    mime_types_error: The allowed file extensions are:jpg, png, gif, bmp and pdf
```

But if try to upload a high resolution image of size 2-3 MB, it throws the mime type error message like:

```
The allowed file extensions are:jpg, png, gif, bmp and pdf
```

though the file type belongs to .jpg. Can anyone tell me is this a symfony1 sfvalidator bug? And how can I overcome this?

Comment: What is your `upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size` in your php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried the normal sfValidatorFile ? 
It's used quite often in my sf1.4 app and I never had any issues.

```
$this->setWidget('file', new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array()));
$this->setValidator('file', new sfValidatorFile(array(
        'required'  => true,
        'path'      => sfConfig::get("sf_upload_dir").'/images',
        'max_size' => 5120000,
        'mime_types' => array('image/jpeg','image/pjpeg','image/png','image/x-png')
    ),
    array(
        'max_size' => 'Your file is too big',
        'mime_types' => 'This type of file is not allowed',
        'required' => 'Please choose a file'
    )
));
```

Use this in your desired Form class and customize the 'mime_types'.

If this doens't work you could try using [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.identifyimage.php). 
I hope this helps!